# Displaying message only when text in search box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery which queries a PHP file. Currently, when no results are found, the PHP file returns no HTML code so the script displays a message saying "No results were found.". However, when there are no search terms in the search box and the query string is empty this message is still displayed. How can I get it so that the message is only shown when there is text in the search box?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web';
        window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/1/';
        document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
        if(search==''){
            window.location.hash='';
            document.title='My Search Script';
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                if(response !=""){
                $("#result").html(response);
                } else {
                $("#result").html("No results were found.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the value of `search` when you search with an empty string?  why doesn't your `if(search='')` test catch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is still firing even when there is nothing in the search field. Only make the request if the field isn't empty.